# Editing my Gmail username

Tags: gmail

By mistake, I gave a wrong email address to my employer, who is very strict about any changes. My email address was `prescottjkn91s23@gmail.com`. Instead I wrote `prescottjkn91@gmail.com`.
I will be receiving multiple work related emails from my employer and my job involves a lot of travelling with the consequence that I won't meet my employer for another six weeks.

Is there any way to edit the username or at least a way by which I can send / receive emails only for my employer?

Answer (score 3):

It is not possible to change username if you are using gmail.
https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/19870?hl=en

However, you can create new account with another username and setup redirect on accounts settings pages:
https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#settings/accounts